# Como compilar en visual studio code

Tags: c, visual-studio, linux, ssh

Hola tengo instalado el visual studio code y con ssh me estoy conectando de manera remota a mi maquina virtual de linux. El punto es que estoy intentando compilar un código en c sencillo en mi visual studio code.
en el terminal ya le di a
`sudo atp install gcc`
me sale este error ya intente poner `gcc --version` y me sale todo en orden.

```
prueba.c:1:9: fatal error: stdio.h: No existe el archivo o el directorio
    1 | #include<stdio.h>
compilation terminated. '
```

Comment: Lee [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Las imágenes mostrando código o errores no son bien recibidas, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/479980/edit) tu pregunta agregando el error como texto

Comment: Comprobaste que `gcc` este instalado correctamente? Usa `gcc --version` ...

Comment: @MrDave1999 cuando le di gcc --version me salio esto `stefhanie1@stefhanie1-VirtualBox:~/Documentos/arquitectura$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.`

Comment: Y al compilar manualmente te sale el mismo error?

Comment: @Pablochaches hola gracias por la ayuda, vi que hay paquetes rotos en mi versión de ubuntu así que tuve que instalar otra vez y si funciono, gracias por la ayuda